# POST/GET request и tor hidden service (.onion)

Tags: http-redirect, php

Здравствуйте, люди. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли отправить POST запрос к tor hidden service (то есть к хосту, который имеет .onion домен). На VPS установлен tor, и он открывает socks5 (127.0.0.1:9050) для доступа в tor-сеть. Пробую примерно как в примере ниже, но с той стороны нет ответа, как будто ничего не доходит.

```
<?php
$proxy = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "9050";
$url = "https://mydomain.onion/input.php";

$fp = fsockopen($proxy, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$url = @parse_url($url);

if($fp)
{
    //читаем данные
    if(($data = @file_get_contents('php://input')) === false)$data = '';

    $request  = "POST {$url['path']}." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
   $request .= "Host: {$url['host']}\r\n";
   if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))$request .= "User-Agent:    {$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']}\r\n";
   $request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
   $request .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n";
   $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n";
   //шлем
   fwrite($fp, $headers.$data);
   //ответ
   while(!feof($fp))  echo fread($fp, 1024);
   fclose($fp);
}
else die; 
?>
```

Comment: Отправлять POST точно можно - ибо луковые сети ничем от обычных не отличаются, кроме (мнимой) анонимности. Как следствие - проблемы могут возникать в виде антибот-защиты, которые необходимо выявлять. Для начала попробуйте просто загрузить страницу в обычном браузере. Если все хорошо (может быть плохо, ибо tor-сайты банятся очень быстро в последнее время), то отследите заголовки, которые помимо post-запроса отправляет браузер. Ну и т.д. и т.п. пишем стандартный парсер. Ну и мелкий момент - 30 секунд на запрос к tor? Последний раз у меня хайденвики грузилась минуты 4...

Comment: Спасибо за мелкий момент :)

В общем проблема решается через curl. Примерный вид скрипта запостил в ответе.

Comment: Ой что-то в кашу все склеилось, но разобрать, я думаю, не проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению,  не хватает респектов для ответа на собственный вопрос, поэтому кину сюда.

```
$proxy = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "9050";
$url = "https://mydomain.onion/input.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7 );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy.':'.$port );
ob_start();

curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
var_dump($result);
```

Тут нет собственно самих данных, они добавляются также curl_setopt